# Why is my state array variable being treated as "pass-by-reference" and mutated when I use it as a parameter to another function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a simple component here where I set a state variable called `input` to the value of an array of numbers. Then, within `useEffect` I call a function that randomizes the initial state array, and puts the results in a new state variable called `output`.

I need my input array to stay in the same order. However, it is being mutated when I call the `shuffleArray` function.

I thought there was no way to alter the value held by a variable passed as a parameter, which would be possible if JavaScript supported passing by reference.

```js
const App = () => {
  const [input, setInput] = React.useState([90, 32, 28, 8, 21, 24, 64, 92, 45, 98, 22, 21, 6, 3, 27, 18, 11, 56, 16, 42, 36, 2, 60, 38, 24, 8, 16, 76, 62, 14, 84, 32, 24, 18, 8, 5, 25, 68, 65, 26, 22, 2, 52, 84, 30, 8, 2, 90, 5, 34, 56, 16, 42, 36]);

  const [output, setOutput] = React.useState([]);

  const shuffleArray = (array) => {
    for (let i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        let j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
        let temp = array[i];
        array[i] = array[j];
        array[j] = temp;
    }
    return array;
  }
  
  React.useEffect(() => {
      setOutput(shuffleArray(input));
  }, [])
  
  return (
    <div>
      [
       {
           input.length > 0 ?
               input.map((n, i) => (
                   <span key={i}>
                     { (i? ", " : "") + n }
                   </span>
               ))
               : 
               "No array..."
       }
      ]
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: `shuffleArray` mutates the array in place. It does not create a copy of the array first.

Comment: Please review [Is JavaScript a pass-by-reference or pass-by-value language?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/518000) - you cannot change what a variable is assigned to, however objects can be mutated without reassigning a variable. These are two different concepts.

Comment: @VLAZ Ohhhhh wait. I was aware that Objects were the exception to the rule. I wasn't considering that the Array is indeed an Object. Okay that makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: Objects aren't really exceptions. The rule is the same - you cannot change what a variable is assigned to by passing its value to a function: `foo(x)` cannot reassign `x` via the parameter only. However, primitives cannot be mutated - if you wan to change the `4` to a `2`, for example, you need to do it through reassignment. Object properties can be altered without reassigning.

Comment: @VLAZ Perhaps my phrasing was off. But I get it. My understanding of the rule was simply incorrect. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input is changed because that's the way pass-by-value works. Primitives cannot be mutated without reassignment. However, when it comes to objects (and arrays, as in this case), *properties* of the object *can be* mutated without reassignment.

If you want to keep input unchanged, you can use [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) instead and manipulate a copy of the array.

```js
const App = () => {
  const [input, setInput] = React.useState([90, 32, 28, 8, 21, 24, 64, 92, 45, 98, 22, 21, 6, 3, 27, 18, 11, 56, 16, 42, 36, 2, 60, 38, 24, 8, 16, 76, 62, 14, 84, 32, 24, 18, 8, 5, 25, 68, 65, 26, 22, 2, 52, 84, 30, 8, 2, 90, 5, 34, 56, 16, 42, 36]);

  const [output, setOutput] = React.useState([]);

  const shuffleArray = (array) => {
    const shuffled = Array.from(array);
    for (let i = shuffled.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        let j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
        let temp = shuffled[i];
        shuffled[i] = shuffled[j];
        shuffled[j] = temp;
    }
    return shuffled;
  }
  
  React.useEffect(() => {
      setOutput(shuffleArray(input));
  }, [])
  
  return (
    <div>
      [
       {
           input.length > 0 ?
               input.map((n, i) => (
                   <span key={i}>
                     { (i? ", " : "") + n }
                   </span>
               ))
               : 
               "No array..."
       }
      ]
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Javascript actually passes Objects and Arrays by "Copy of a Reference" as explained in this SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13104500/17704187

So your `shuffleArray` function actually mutates the contents of the input array.